# Why is the object, and not the memory address of the object, the first argument in this example c++ snippet?

Tags: c++

I have a pretty basic c++ question (coming from a Python background).

I'm working through an example from the 'tour basics' book by Bjarne Stroustrup. Its basically this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Vector {
    int sz;         // number of elements in vector
    double* elem;   // pointer to elements in vector
};

void vector_init(Vector& v, int s)
{
    v.elem = new double[s];     // allocate an array of s doubles
    v.sz = s;
}

int main()
{

    Vector v;
    vector_init(v, 10);
    return 0;
};
```

What is causing me confusion is that the function `vector_init` takes a *memory* address of a vector for its first argument, but when its being used in the `main`, we are passing the vector `v` itself, not its memory address (which I assume would be `&v` rather than `v`).

This is working code and it compiles, but why do you not need to give the memory address as an argument here?

Comment: vector_init is taking a *reference* to the vector (a reference is an alias to an object)

Comment: The parameter is actually a reference to an object, not an address of the object. You wouldn't be able to pass `null`.

Comment: `Vector& v` is a reference, not a pointer. If it was a pointer, you'd need `&`.

Comment: its one of the early sins of c++ to have the same symbol `&` for related but different things (address-of vs reference type)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer (or reference?) to the dup question. Things are much clearer now,